# Criar banner rotativo com AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando criar um banner rotativo com AngularJS. Quero que a acada 1 minuto seja sorteado uma posição de um array de imagens e seja exibido a imagem referente.

Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.controller('BannerAnuncios', function($scope, $timeout){

    var banners = ["imagem1.jpg", "imagem2.jpg", "imagem3.jpg", "imagem4.jpg", "imagem5.jpg"];
    var count = banners.length;

    function rotationBanner(){  
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        $scope.banner = banners[i];
        $timeout(rotationBanner(), 60000)
    }

    rotationBanner();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" ng-controller='BannerAnuncios'>
      <img ng-src={{banner}}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu diria que seu problema é na linha

```
$timeout(rotationBanner(), 60000)
```

Repare que você chama a função `$timeout` e no primeiro parâmetro você já invoca a função `rotationBanner`, uma função que não retorna nada sendo que era esperado que você passasse uma função como parâmetro, como por exemplo:

```
$timeout(function(){rotationBanner()}, 60000)
```

Ou simplificando mais um pouco, como sua função não precisa de nenhum parâmetro seria possível simplesmente fazer assim

```
$timeout(rotationBanner, 60000)
```

Comment: perfeito, obrigado.